# How to expand or collapse a div by setting a button on it using PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I' am using php and javascript for expanding or collapsing some divs [which must be collapsed bydeafult] by setting up a button[whose text should be expand bydefault] on a div when i click on that button the div gets expanded and text of that button should be automatically changes to "collapse" and again if i click that collapse button the div should be closed and text changes to bydefault as "expand" and bydefault all the divs should be closed heres the code given below i am using :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function change()
{
if(document.getElementById("myButton1").value=="expand")
{
document.getElementById("myButton1").value="collapse";

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myButton1").click(function(){
  $("div.container").hide("slow");
  });
}
else
{
document.getElementById("myButton1").value="expand";

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myButton1").click(function(){
  $("div.container").show("slow");
  });

 }
}

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++)
{
echo"<div style='position:relative;border:1px solid #A5BEBE;background-color: #E7EFEF;     width:100%; height:300px;'> <input onclick='change()' type='button' value='expand' id='myButton1'     style='position:relative;left:85%;top:4%;background-    color:#B20000;color:white;width:70px;height:20px;font-size:15px;' >";

echo "<div class='container' style='border:1px solid #A5BEBE;background-color:     white;width:100%;height:92.5%;'>
  some text here
</div>";
echo "</div><br><br>";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

i just a beginner in php so tried my best but dint get the desired result please help me out of this thanks in advance

**here is some more info**

its not working for my actual code which is:

```
    while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery))
    {
    $title = $runrows ['sometext'];
    $desc = $runrows ['sometext'];
    $url = $runrows ['sometext'];
$a = $runrows ['sometext'];
$b = $runrows ['sometext'];
$c = $runrows ['sometext'];
$d = $runrows ['sometext'];
$e = $runrows ['sometext'];
$f = $runrows ['sometext'];
$g = $runrows ['sometext']; 


echo "
<div style='position:relative;border:1px solid #A5BEBE;background-color: #E7EFEF;width:84%;'>     <input onclick='change()' type='button' value='expand' class='myButton'         style='position:relative;left:85%;top:4%;background-    color:#B20000;color:white;width:70px;height:30px;font-size:15px;' >  <b><p style='padding-    bottom:2px;font-size:30px;'><font color='red'>".$title."</font></p></b><p><b>sometext :</b>$desc<br>
<b> sometext:-</b><a href='".$url."'>$url</a><br>
<b>sometext :</b>$b<br>
<b>sometext :</b>$c<br>
<b>sometext :</b>$d<br>
<b>sometext :</b>$e<br>
<b>sometext :</b>$f<br>
<b>sometext :</b>$g</p>";
echo "<div class='container' style='border:1px solid #A5BEBE;background-color: white;'>";
 include ('botfunction.php'); 
echo "</div>";
echo "</div><br>";

}
```

@TheGr8_Nik your code is not working for this . this is the small part of actual code but its not working there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change your code so:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.myButton').click(function(){
      if ( this.value === 'collapse' ) {
        // if it's open close it
        open = false;
        this.value = 'expand';
        $(this).next("div.container").hide("slow");
      }
      else {
        // if it's close open it
        open = true;
        this.value = 'collapse';
        $(this).siblings("[value='collapse']").click(); //to collapse the open divs
        $(this).next("div.container").show("slow");
      }
    });

  });
</script>
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/mpnraLzk/)

Comment: i run your code for all divs its working but its expanding and collapsing all four divs while i click on only one expand button . please try to run it in the whole code u'll get the problem

Comment: @MunanshuMadaan - is because `$("div.container")` find all divs with the `container` class, you can try with the jQuery function `next` (https://api.jquery.com/next/) that finds the next sibling element, in your case the div

Comment: so how can i make this working for one at a time by this (api.jquery.com/next) can you explain this...

Comment: @MunanshuMadaan - updated my code, now should work. You should not use the same id for more buttons, change the `id="myButton1"` in `class="myButton"` in your php code

Comment: okay good one @TheGr8_Nik its working but they are not closed bydefault...the divs must be closed on loading or refreshing

Comment: Add `style="display:none"` in the container generation

Comment: Thanks but all the divs are visible. when we are expanding one div only that div should be visible rest should be hidden

Comment: @MunanshuMadaan - I have added the row to close the opened div and added a jsFiddle example too.

Comment: you have to hide the other divs leaving the only one which is selected please help me out !!

Comment: see my new ques here  ""http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244856/how-to-hide-other-divs-and-show-only-which-is-presently-clicked-by-button"" you'll get the problem @TheGr8_Nik

Comment: @MunanshuMadaan - I don't understand what doesn't work in my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mpnraLzk/

Comment: your code is working but their is another thing i want to ask that how to show present div only that is being clicked while hiding the other ones...see the link to my new ques you'll get it...

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$("#hide").click(function(){
  $("p").hide();
});

$("#show").click(function(){
  $("p").show();
});
```

or switch function:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("p").toggle();
});
```

Here is the working example:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_toggle

Comment: you should't use `w3schools`, use the offical jQuery site instead: https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: @Tikky see the text here of the button is not changing i want that text should be changed with respect of expanding or collapsing and can you show me this for all the divs beacause it doesnot work properly for all divs

Answer (score 0):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z34qwrgn/)

You can use this

Script

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#con div button',function(){
     if($(this).parent().hasClass('expand'))
     { $(this).parent().removeClass('expand');
       $(this).html('Expand');}
        else{$(this).parent().addClass('expand');
       $(this).html('Collapse');}

    })

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="con">
    <div class="expand"><button >Collapse</button></div>
    <div class="expand"><button >Collapse</button></div>
    <div class="expand"><button >Collapse</button></div>
    <div class="expand"><button >Collapse</button></div>
</div>
```

This will expand and collapse div's based on the container.

Comment: the div con is changing its size because its not a button and can you make them closed bydefault and also adjust its speed to slow when it expands or collapse..